# Write a function which will automatically determine its return value by judging the type of each of its parameters

Tags: c++, templates, macros

The `max()` function in the `<algorithm>` header doesn't support two parameters of different datatypes. So I tried to write my own code using `template` and `#if`, `#else` and `#endif` macros. My code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class type1, class type2>
#if sizeof(type1) >= sizeof(type2)
    type1 max(type1 a, type2 b){
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }
#else
    type2 max(type1, type2){
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }
#endif

int main(){
    int a, d; long long b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "The max is " << max(a, b) << ".\n";
    std::cin >> c >> d;
    std::cout << "The max is " << max(c, d) << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now obviously the code is not valid as it is raising a syntax error (maybe I misunderstood the way those macros work as I'm new to this topic as well as the template):

```
|Line 05 | error: missing binary operator before token "type1"    |
|        | In function 'type2 max(type1, type2)':                 |
|Line 11 | error: 'a' was not declared in this scope              |
|Line 11 | error: 'b' was not declared in this scope              |
```

I would like to know if it is possible to build such a program and how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix macros with templates like this; macros will be evaluated first and won't interact with templates as you expected.

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to declare the return type explicitly,

```
// if sizeof(type1) >= sizeof(type2), then declare the return type as type1
// otherwise type2
template <class type1, class type2>
std::conditional_t<sizeof(type1) >= sizeof(type2), type1, type2>
max(type1 a, type2 b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Or you can just use `auto`. The return type would be deduced automatically as the common type determined by the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). For `max(int, long long)` and `max(long long, int)`, the return type would be `long long`, the same as the above version. (Note that the common type might be different to the above version; e.g. for `max(short, bool)` the return type would be `int` instead of `short`.)

```
template <class type1, class type2>
auto max(type1 a, type2 b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t9tJHR9RAUlPYoJS)

Comment: What do mean by common type. Can you explain please? An example should make everything clear.